# Cloud-formation : Provided Arn is not in correct format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to trigger a AWS Task-schedular from CLoudwatch every 2 hours which will perform some of operation .

Below is my Cloudformation template

```
  TaskSchedule:
    Type: "AWS::Events::Rule"
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      Description: >
        Run every two hours.
      ScheduleExpression:  !Ref TaskRate #rate(1 day)  #cron (15 10 * * ? *) #(0 0 * * *) #!Ref LambdaRate
      State: ENABLED
      #Targets:
      #  - Arn: !Ref ecsCluster.Arn     #!Sub ${TaskDefinitionDaily.Arn}
      #    Id: TaskSchedule
      #    EcsParameters:
      #      TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref TaskDefinitionDaily
      #      TaskCount: 1
      #      LaunchType: 'FARGATE'
      #      PlatformVersion: 'LATEST'
      Targets:
        - Id: 'ECSTarget'
          Arn: !Ref ecsCluster.Arn     #!Sub ${TaskDefinitionDaily.Arn}
          EcsParameters:
            TaskCount: 1
            TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref 'TaskDefinitionDaily'
```

Now when I am trying to run the above Cloudformation template I am getting below error . I am new in CFT and don't know what is causing this.

```
Provided Arn is not in correct format. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
```

Please let me know what might I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access the `Arn` attribute of `ecsCluster` but you are using `!Ref` to do so. This doesn't work. You have to use `!GetAtt` to receive an attribute.

Try the following

```
TaskSchedule:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  DeletionPolicy: Delete
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Run every two hours.
    ScheduleExpression:  !Ref TaskRate
    State: ENABLED
    Targets:
      - Id: ECSTarget
        Arn: !GetAtt ecsCluster.Arn
        EcsParameters:
          TaskCount: 1
          TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref TaskDefinitionDaily
```

Comment: ecsCluster is parameter hence can't be used as !GetAtt

Comment: If this is the case then you should use `!Ref ecsCluster` (without `.Arn`)